# How can a host connect to a domain if the domain address changes and the entry is still cached?

Tags: dns

I’m studying the DNS system and when I got to DNS cache I started wondering how could a host reach a cached domain if the domain were to change its IP.

Basically, the idea is: The host connects to domain `foo.com` and uses IP address A. The entry is cached in the DNS servers on the way between the host and the destination, as well as on the host itself. Now, the domain `foo.com` changes ip to a value B. How can the host reach the destination if the entry is pointing to A? I know that there is an expiration for cached entries, but of course in this case I consider the entry to be fully valid while the host changes IP.

Comment: You need to continue reading.  If you're studying the DNS system and haven't come across what a **TTL** is yet, then you should find different study material.  It's a fundamental piece to the puzzle (and the answer to your question).

Comment: Actually, I did take the TTL in consideration but for some reason the professor didn't accept it as an answer. No idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is “it doesn’t”, not until the cached TTL expires. This is why it’s common practice to reduce the TTL to a very low value in advance of major changes. Your workarounds would be to use the IP address or entries in the hosts file until DNS has caught up.

In the case where the *wrong* data has been published with a very high TTL, you’ll want to consult [What happens when your TTL gets screwed up in your DNS record?](https://serverfault.com/q/630043/152073).

Comment: And to expand upon "it doesn't", to workaround this limitation, it is possible to configure a service at the old IP to proxy a connection through to the new IP.  This will cover the traffic during the propagation time.